# Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device) after opening R studio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce some graph with ggplot in R studio. However, although the code runs smoothly, they are not created. I have tried with dev.off(), but the error message appears. I have also noticed that the error is present also just opening Rstudio. Does anyone has some clue of why I cannot shut down device 1?
Many thanks!

Comment: device 1 is the "Null Device".  You cannot shut it down and it does not display anything.  To get a display,  start a new device.  Please take a look at the help page `?Devices`

Comment: To clarify @G5W 's comment, to start a new device and then shut it down would be something like `pdf('myplot.pdf', height = 5, width = 5); <insert plotting code here>; dev.off()`

Answer (score 3):

I think we should take a step back. You tried using `dev.off()` (and got an error) but the initial problem was a failure to create a plot using ggplot. The most common cause of "they are not created" is not understanding the need to `print` the `grid` object that `ggplot`, returns. There is an implicit `print` at the console but not inside functions. This will create the behavior you describe:

```
dev.off() # shuts down my interactive graphics device
          # could also have used system point and click to close an open window
p11 <- function() {myplot <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1,y=1), aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()
                   dev.off() }


dev.off()
Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
```

If you had opened a pdf() or png() device inside that function there would have been a device to print to. See `?Devices`